# Xamarin.form shows different UI on iOS Simulator and xaml preview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

I am using Xamarin Studio version6.2.1 and working on xamrin.form.I create xaml design by focusing on preview but when i run same code on **iOS Simulator the UI scattered**, while the Android device have same UI as shown in Preview. **Check blue area on screen and background image as well**.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is because of image resolution is higher than screen size.

try Aspect="AspectFit" in image tag.

```
<Image Source="Background.png" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
```

For more information please check the link bellow.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Comment: thanks @Waleed it works for me.. Could you also suggest why XAML preview and iOS Simulator have different UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the size of iOS simulator and XAML previewer is different. Make sure your XAML code is responsive. Hope it helps!

Comment: I dont think there is any size option for XAML previewer in Xamarin, if it is then let me know.